# How does this Forum scraping code work specific_messages data structure

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I would like to thank the User Pythonista for giving me this very useful code a few months back that solved my problem. I'm still however confused how the code function due to my lack of knowledge of HTML and the Beautiful soup library.

I'm confused about what part does specific_messages data strcuture play in this program ?

I'm also confused about how does the code save the various posts ?
and how does it check the user of the post?

```
import requests, pprint
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as BS

url = "https://forums.spacebattles.com/threads/the-wizard-of-woah-and-the-impossible-methods-of-necromancy.337233/"
r = requests.get(url)
soup = BS(r.content, "html.parser")

#To find all posts from a specific user everything below this is for all posts
specific_messages = soup.findAll('li', {'data-author': 'The Wizard of Woah!'})


#To find every post from every user
posts = {}

message_container = soup.find('ol', {'id':'messageList'})
messages = message_container.findAll('li', recursive=0)
for message in messages:
    author = message['data-author']
    #or don't encode to utf-8 simply for printing in shell
    content = message.find('div', {'class':'messageContent'}).text.strip().encode("utf-8")
    if author in posts:
        posts[author].append(content)
    else:
        posts[author] = [content]
pprint.pprint(posts)
```

Answer (score 1):

specific_messages = soup.findAll('li', {'data-author': 'The Wizard of Woah!'})

1. soup is the BeautifulSoup Object that is needed to parse the html
2. findAll() is a function that finds all the parameters you passed in the html code
3. li is the tag that needs to be found.
4. data-author is html attribute which will be searched inside

   tags

   The Wizard of Woah! is author name.

so basically that line is searching for all the

tag with the attribute data-author who have a name The Wizard of Woah!

and findall returns multiple line so you need to loop through it so that you can get each line and it is appending to a list.

thats all

Comment: Thanks I'm just a bit confused about what part the variable plays as it isn't reffered to anywhere else in the script